# webpack dev server port

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I need to change which port `webpack-dev-server` listen to.

Up to now, I've created these there files:

- [webpack.common.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/134e19006a6f8da06bf4123c35d8a8a7)
- [webpack.dev.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/365e8cc433ef629d6246776dce0e3092)
- [webpack.prod.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/919e6228b753cbe67f72edfd613a8c99)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not created a package.json file it will be good if you make one and have a code block like this:

```
{
  "name": "someName",
  "description": "description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --devtool eval --progress --colors",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js -p"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-runtime",
      "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
  }
}
```

You may remove the un used modules. 
Then run : `npm start`
And it will run on port 8080

If you start your dev server without package.json. 
You may simply run following from terminal.

```
webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080
```